# Writable nested Django serializer with string instead of dict

Tags: python, django, serialization, nested

The Django Rest Framework docs have an example for writable nested serializers, see http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers.

I am interested in the case where the related `Track` model has only one field (`title`) besides the foreign key field. I thus modified it to read:

**models.py**

```
class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Track(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='tracks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('album', 'title')
```

**serializers.py**

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('title',)

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tracks_data = validated_data.pop('tracks')
        album = Album.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for track_data in tracks_data:
            Track.objects.create(album=album, **track_data)
        return album
```

**now run:**

```
>>> data = {
    'album_name': 'The Grey Album',
    'artist': 'Danger Mouse',
    'tracks': [
        {'title': 'Public Service Announcement'},
        {'title': 'What More Can I Say'},
        {'title': 'Encore'},
    ],
}
>>> serializer = AlbumSerializer(data=data)
>>> serializer.is_valid()
True
>>> serializer.save()
<Album: Album object>
```

**Question:**

I need the tracks in the serialized data to be structured as a list of track title strings, instead of a list of dicts `{'title': title}`, like this:

```
>>> data = {
    'album_name': 'The Grey Album',
    'artist': 'Danger Mouse',
    'tracks': [
        'Public Service Announcement',
        'What More Can I Say',
        'Encore',
    ],
}
```

I have attempted adapting `AlbumSerializers`'s `to_representation` and `to_internal_value` methods, but could not get it to work with the requirement that the serializer be writable. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [serializermethodfield](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

```
tracks = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_tracks(self, obj):
    return obj.tracks.values_list('title', flat=True)

def create(self, validated_data):
    data = self.context['request'].data.copy()
    tracks_data = data.get('tracks', [])
    album = Album.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for track_data in tracks_data:
        Track.objects.create(album=album, **track_data)
    return album
```

Comment: yes you are right, if you want to write you can override `create` method.

Comment: In the `create` method, we only have `validated_data` which does not contain read-only fields. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: try `data = self.context['request'].data.copy()` inside create

Comment: Thanks! Maybe you can update your initial answer to reflect the writable condition.

Comment: glad to help you, add `create`